# Mainen or Maitoshi used for every year?

Tags: translation, word-choice, words, readings, multiple-readings

I see Mainen and Maitoshi used for every year? Is there any difference and why would one be used over another?

Comment: According to a dictionary http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/thsrs/12831/meaning/m0u/ : "毎年(まいとし)／毎年(まいねん)… [使い分け] 話し言葉としては、「まいねん」の方が、やや改まった感じを与える。"

Comment: P.S. ↑ which is roughly saying: *mainen* sounds more formal than *maitoshi*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know there is no difference except that maitoshi is used much more frequently.

Answer (score 3):

> http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q115611556 
> 　
> Q. 毎年は 「まいとし」 「まいねん」 どっちですか？
>
> A. どちらの読み方でも問題ありませんよ。  日常会話とか会議報告とか、それぞれの雰囲気にあった読み方を選んでください。

So this person suggests that "Mainen" sounds more formal (more business -like), and I agree.

「とし」 makes me think of this character ( 歳 ), but it may be just me.

> dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/206813/meaning/m0u/ -- まいさい【毎歳】 === 毎年。としごと。